# sendSMS() method can't read a String

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know that there is some obvious mistake, but I tried many things and can't get this method to read global String:

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber) {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    String message = mMessage;
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
    int messageCount = parts.size();

    Log.i("Message Count", "Message Count: " + messageCount);
    Log.i("Order", message);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    for (int j = 0; j < messageCount; j++) {
        sentIntents.add(sentPI);
        deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
    }

    // ---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sms_sent,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), generic_failure,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), no_service,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), radio_off,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {

            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sms_delivered,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sms_not_delivered,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI,
            deliveredPI);
    /*
     * sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents,
     * deliveryIntents);
     */
}
```

This method is in MainActivity which holds ViewPager fragments. Strings are gathered and concatenated in fragment with following method:

```
public void getListToString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(ReviewItem item : mCurrentReviewItems){
        sb.append(item.getTitle() + ": " + item.getDisplayValue() + "\n");
    }

    String msg = sb.toString();
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setMessage(msg);              
}
```

To be sure - I've made up Logs with mMessage and Toasts. Every single item is showed, but sendSMS() don't want to send it. Though, when in String message instead of mMessage I put "some string here" it works perfectly. Anyone can catch what makes public String mMessage unaccesable for sendTextMessage?

Comment: I notice that you've commented out the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method. Are you sure you're not hitting the max character limit for `sendTextMessage()`?

Comment: It worked on other apps without it so that may be not the case. Anyway, I'm using Moto G so it would be hard to hit the limit ;)

Comment: I don't think you understand what the character limit means. The SMS protocol defines a 160 character limit (for plain ASCII) for a single message. This number may be lower depending on the alphabet used. If the total message is longer than this, it needs to be split and sent with the multi-part method. This doesn't have anything to do with the device model. I suggest you test with the multi-part method, as `sendTextMessage()` will just fail silently if the message is too long.

Comment: It works! I'm a friggin' moron - why didn't I used that? <facepalm> Big THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your problem is that your String is exceeding the maximum character length for a single SMS message, and needs to be split and sent with the `sendMultipartTextMessage()`.

This maximum length will depend on the character bit-size of the alphabet used: for the standard GSM 7-bit alphabet, it is 160 characters; for an 8-bit alphabet, it's 140 characters; and for a 16-bit alphabet (which would include any non-Latin Unicode characters) it is only 70.

If the message you're attempting to send exceeds the length limit, `sendTextMessage()` will fail silently, with no error or Exception thrown, and no indication of the attempt written to the Provider (if applicable).